# NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'views.showusersignin' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'userid': u'rec.0'}' not found

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I looked many discussion on stackoverflow but none of them helpful.So i decided to paste my code here.so please kindly help me out where i am doing wrong.thanks

**Here is  urls.py**

```
(r'^showusersignin/(?P<userid>\d+)/$', 'views.showusersignin'),
```

**Here is defination in views.py**

```
def showusersignin(request,userid):
```

**Here is signin.html**

```
{%for rec in records.object_list%}

        <tr>
            <td width = "15%">
               <a href="{%url views.showusersignin userid='rec.0' %}">{{rec.0}}</a>
            </td>
            <td width = "15%">
                {{rec.1}}
            </td>
            <td width = "15%">
                {{rec.2}}
            </td>

        </tr>
 {%endfor%}
```

**Error on Server**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    mysite/signin
Django Version: 1.2.5
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'views.showusersignin' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'userid': u'rec.0'}' not found.
Exception Location: /base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.2/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 385
Python Executable:  /base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    ['/base/data/home/apps/s~bgshelloworld/9.363836595528814694', '/base/data/home/apps/s~bgshelloworld/9.363836595528814694', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python27.zip', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.2', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/markupsafe-0.15', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/setuptools-0.6c11', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1', '/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10']
Server time:    Thu, 13 Dec 2012 11:11:23 +0000
```

Comment: paste the inital part of your `urls.py` where you do `urlpatterns = patterns(...` My guess is, you are not specifying the correct app there.

Comment: Another possibility is: `<a href="{%url views.showusersignin rec.0 %}">{{rec.0}}</a>` - since you specify `userid=` django considers that a kwarg, rather than a required parameter

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two things wrong.

Firstly, you have put `'rec.0'` as a string inside the url tag. I presume you mean to pass the value of that list item, so you should do `userid=rec.0`

Secondly, your URL doesn't have a `userid` argument, because you haven't used a named parameter. Either change it to `r'^showusersignin/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$'`, or change your url tag to `{%url views.showusersignin rec.0 %}`